# Go To A Particular Cell After Inputting Data In Another Cell And Hitting Enter Options

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel sheet and I'm inputting data in A2, B2 and C2; after I hit enter I want the cursor select the next line so I can input information on A3, B3 and C3 and so on

I found this information

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Range("C2").Value <> "" Then
Range("A3").Select
End If
End Sub
```

But it only works one time, how can I repeat this process over and over

Thanks for your help.....

Comment: Type "VBA loop" into Google and see what you get.

Answer (score 6):

Another way.

1. If you type anywhere in Col A, the selection will move to Col B.
2. If you type anywhere in Col B, the selection will move to Col C.
3. If you type anywhere in Col C, the selection will move back to Col A (Next Line).

**Code**: This goes in the relevant sheet code area.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Offset(, 1).Select
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Offset(, 1).Select
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Offset(1, -2).Select
        End If
    End If
Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: @user2270747: Works? You doubted it? :P

Answer (score 1):

in your Tools>options dialog what is the settings for **Move Selection after Enter** ?:

[image]

there is more information on [Tech Republic: Three ways to control Excel's cursor movement during data entry](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/three-ways-to-control-excels-cursor-movement-during-data-entry/8292) which will show you how to do exactly what you want...

Basically, select the range cells you want to enter data in, Excel selects the first cell, then after each entry, hit the {Tab} key. *Excel will move the carat to the next empty cell in your selection*

Voila !

Comment: Right now I have this option to move to the right every time I hit enter, however after inputting the info on cell C3 and I hit enter it moves to D3 and I need to select A4......so next time I input info on A4, B4 and C4 and I hit again the enter should go to A5 and so on

Answer (score 1):

If you need to involve VBA to that there are to properties which set direction and status respectively:

```
Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight 
Application.MoveAfterReturn = True
```