# Offset to different column after entering data in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables. Both tables are the same size, located in columns I:X and AB:AQ (offset by 19 columns start-to-start).

I want when I enter a number in a cell within the left table, to go 19 columns to the right after pressing enter. Then, once entering text into the active cell in the right table, return 19 cells to the left table.

I found [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952263/go-to-a-particular-cell-after-inputting-data-in-another-cell-and-hitting-enter-o), but I wasn't able to apply it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(9)) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Offset(, 19).Select
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(10)) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Offset(, 19).Select
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(11)) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Offset(, 19).Select
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(12)) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Offset(, 19).Select
'etc...  
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(42)) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Offset(, -19).Select
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(43)) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Offset(, -19).Select
        End If
    End If
Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

As an alternative, if it can recognize that the cell entered is within columns I:X and just offset 19 columns after pressing enter (and then the reverse), this would be fine.

A second alternative, if it is easier, changing the function of the **Page Up** and **Page Down** keys, I would not need to check which column I am in.

Lastly, this should only work on a particular sheet **Tracking**.

Comment: I imagine you want to do this, in order to go easier from one column to the other one. Normally, the way this is done, is by hiding the columns in between. In case you don't know how to do this: right-click the column header, and choose "Hide" from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.  Make sure the code is in the 'Tracking' worksheet code module:

[image]

And here is the code you would use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngChange1 As Range
    Dim rngChange2 As Range

    Set rngChange1 = Range("I:X")
    Set rngChange2 = Range("AB:AQ")

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(rngChange1, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(, 19).Value = Target.Value
    End If

    If Not Intersect(rngChange2, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(, -19).Value = Target.Value
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I did have to modify    `Target.Offset(,19).Value = Target.Value`    to be    `Target.Offset(,19).Select`   for what I wanted. With that change it works perfectly! Thanks!